# Is the int(n) is necessary for if-else range statements here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Here in if statement can i use n instate of int(n) ?
Give me the right instruction.
Thanks in advance.

```
n = int(input())

if int(n) in range(2,5):
     print(n)
```

Comment: For Python 3, you need to apply `int` once to turn the string into an integer.  In the example, the second call to `int` is redundant, since `n` is already an integer at that point.

Comment: second int is redundant in all versions of python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using int in the first line forces n to be an integer. So, the second is unnecessary.